# Using a render method instead of direct return

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner in React.

This code works fine to render my cards.
The function **Card** is called directly in the Render method of the Game class:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import unknownCard from './assets/img/unknown.png';

function Card(props) {
   return (
     <img onClick={props.onClick} src={props.path}>        
     </img>
   );
}


class Game extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        texte: 'bonjour'
    };
}


handleClick(i) {
    this.setState({
        texte: i
    });
}

render() {

const imgContext = require.context('./assets/img/cards', false, /\.png/);
const images = imgContext.keys().map(imgContext);

return (
    <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
            {images.map((object, i) => {
                //Right here
                 return (
                     <Card 
                         key={i}
                         path={object}
                         onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
                     />
                 );
            })}
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
            <div>{this.state.texte}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
}


// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
<Game />,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But I want to use an external Render method.
So I added a method: **renderCard** and called it in the Render of the **Game** class:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import unknownCard from './assets/img/unknown.png';

function Card(props) {
return (
  <img onClick={props.onClick} src={props.path}>        
  </img>
);
}


class Game extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        texte: 'bonjour'
    };
}


handleClick(i) {
    this.setState({
        texte: i
    });
}

// Added that
renderCard(object, i) {
    return (
        <Card 
            key={i}
            path={object}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
        />
    );
}

render() {

const imgContext = require.context('./assets/img/cards', false, /\.png/);
const images = imgContext.keys().map(imgContext);

return (
    <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
            {images.map((object, i) => {
                //That instead
                this.renderCard(object, i)                    
            })}
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
            <div>{this.state.texte}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
}


// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
<Game />,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But that displays nothing (no error).
What I did wrong?

Comment: It should be `return this.renderCard(object, i)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` function has to have a `return` statement. Try below:

```
return (
    <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
            {images.map((object, i) => {
                //That instead
                return this.renderCard(object, i)                    
            })}
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
            <div>{this.state.texte}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `return` in your `map` method

```
{
    images.map((object, i) => {
     return this.renderCard(object, i);
    });
}
```